# Extending generator matrix in coding theory

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

I have an $m \times n$ matrix $M$ where $m < n$ over finite field of size $2^w$. This matrix has the property that every $m \times m$ matrix formed by a $m$-subset of its columns is invertible. Is there a way to extend $M$ into a $m \times (n + k)$ matrix while still preserving this property?

The motivation behind this problem is for erasure coding in coding theory, where $M$ is the generator matrix. I want to extend the code to add more parity bits without needing to re-encode the existing parity bits.

Comment: I think I could help figure out how to determine the maximum number of columns that could satisfy that property, but I'm not sure I know of an algorithm for finding possible columns to add.  Would determining this maximum number be helpful?

Comment: Not too useful for me, unfortunately. I feel that the maximum number is probably just be the size of the field (+/- some constant). I say this because I already know that any submatrix of the Vandermonde matrix must be invertible.